# ¿Alguien sabe cuanta memoria puede llegar a requerir un programa que maneja imágenes de 1080 pixeles?

Tags: c++, c, hardware, arquitectura-de-software

me encuentro desarrollando un proyecto el cual se basa en un programa hecho en c que necesita como input una imagen de 1080 pixeles de resolución. Mi objetivo es lograr hacer funcionar ese programa en un microcontrolador que sea lo más económico posible, es por esa razón que necesito tener una idea de cuánto recurso puede llegar a necesitar un programa con ésas características para elegir el microcontrolador más adecuado.

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a la resolución "vertical" 1080p. A esa resolución vertical suele corresponder una resolución horizontal de 1920. Eso hace un total de 1920x1080 = 2.073.600 pixeles. Es habitual que cada pixel requiera 3 bytes, por lo que el total de memoria que requerirá la imagen "descomprimida" será de unos 6MB. Multiplica por dos como mínimo ese tamaño, pues es normal al procesarla tener una copia. Siendo conservador yo multiplicaría al menos por tres. O sea, unos 20MB sólo para la imagen. Sumale el tamaño del código

Comment: Lo anterior en cuanto a requisitos de memoria. Otra cosa es qué vayas a hacer con esa imagen, pues cuanto mayor es, más píxeles hay que procesar. Y qué restricciones de tiempo tendrás, o sea, de cuánto tiempo dispones para hacer ese procesamiento. Si por ejemplo quieres procesar a 24fps necesitarás procesar 24x1920x1080 = unos 50 millones de pixeles por segundo (unos 150 millones de bytes por segundo)

Comment: Si perdón por la equivocación, gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Yo quisiera que el procesamiento se haga en menos de 5 segundos. ¿Tu crees que con un Arduino uno se pueda lograr?

Comment: Pero qué procesamiento va a ser?

Comment: El de convertir las palabras que se encuentran en la imagen en un archivo .txt para luego convertir ese archivo .txt a uno mp3 para luego reproducirlo mediante un parlante, compañero.

Comment: O sea, quieres hacer OCR... entonces los requisitos no son ya los de la imagen en sí, sino los de la biblioteca OCR que vayas a utlizar. Si quieres que sea muy genérico (en cuanto a los tipos de letra que pueda reconocer) seguramente tendrás que usar algún tipo de red neuronal pre-entrenada. El tamaño de esas redes puede ser grande. Realmente no sabría decirte, pero me parece que la pregunta es demasiado amplia y que deberías investigar un poco más en las soluciones existentes a tu problema, aunque sea sobre PC, para hacerte una idea.

Comment: Si es sobre OCR, éste termino lo había leído hace muy poco, ni me lo recordaba cuando hice la pregunta :P. Justamente por el temor de que vaya a consumir muchos recursos fue que decidí que va a ser en C y no en python. Incluso en python hay videos muy faciles de seguir donde te muestran como extraer el texto de una imagen en menos de 10 lineas de código. Parece que mi objetivo de hacerlo muy barato va a verse truncado, muchas gracias por tu ayuda abulafia :D.

Comment: Desconozco qué potencia tiene un Arduino Uno. Pero una Raspberri Pi es también bastante barata y creo que sí podría con la tarea. De todas formas no me atrevo a garantizar nada tampoco.

Answer (score 3):

Arduino no te sirve para esos propósitos. Tiene sólo 2 KB RAM para variables.

Igualmente, los ESP8266 y ESP32 también están limitados por memoria (520 KB RAM).

Te recomiendo mirar una placa [Raspberry Pi Zero](https://images.techhive.com/images/article/2016/05/pizero1-3-100661193-orig.jpg), que está pensada como alternativa de los MCU ya mencionados.

Hay cámaras disponibles para Raspberry Pi capaces de grabar 1080 a 30 fps, o 720 a 60 fps:

```
Características
Placa de Cámara Oficial Raspberry Pi, compatible con Raspberry Pi y Jetson Nano
Sony IMX219 8-megapixel sensor
Especificaciones de la cámara
Tamaño CCD: 1/4 pulgadas
Apertura (F) : 2,0
Longitud Focal: 3,04mm
Ángulo de visión (diagonal) : 62,2 grados
3280 × 2464 resolución de imagen fija
Soporte para grabación de vídeo 1080p30, 720p60 y 640x480p90
Dimensión: 25mm x 24mm x 9mm
Nota: Para usar la cámara con Raspberry Pi Zero / Zero W / Zero WH, debe comprar un cable específico: Raspberry Pi Zero v1.3.
```

[image: Raspberry Pi Zero]